How to find rows with value on either side of a given value?
Python, Pandas, I have a dataframe containing datetimes and values.
# Create an empty DataFrame with 'timestamp' and 'value' columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'value'])
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

I append data to that frame over time.
At some point, I want to find the value at a timestamp. If it's already in the df, great, easy to find.
However, if the time I'm looking for is between two existing values, how can I find that quickly, and interpolate between those two bracketing values? ChatGPT led me on a merry chase with nothing by invalid comparisons.
Here's what I tried so far, not working:
# Check if the target timestamp exists in the DataFrame
timestamps = df.index

if target_timestamp in timestamps:
# Exact match found
    return df.loc[target_timestamp, 'value']
else:
    # Use searchsorted to find the insertion point
    pos = timestamps.searchsorted(target_timestamp)

    if pos == 0 or pos == len(timestamps) - 1:
        raise ValueError("Target timestamp is out of bounds for interpolation")

    if target_timestamp > timestamps[pos]:
        previous_timestamp = timestamps[pos]
        next_timestamp = timestamps[pos + 1]
    else:
        previous_timestamp = timestamps[pos - 1]
        next_timestamp = timestamps[pos]

    # Interpolating the value
    previous_value = df.loc[previous_timestamp, 'value']
    next_value = df.loc[next_timestamp, 'value']

    # Linear interpolation formula
    interpolated_value = previous_value + (next_value - previous_value) * \
                        (target_timestamp - previous_timestamp) / (next_timestamp - previous_timestamp)

    return interpolated_value


show at least first 10 rows of input (in the form of dict) and desired output

Simulated your dataset as follows:-
import pandas as pd
import random

dti = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=1000, freq="d")
value = [random.random() for x in range(0, 1000)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': value}, index=dti)

and solution as follows:-
# case where dt doesn't exist
dt2 = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-02 10:00:00')

def nearest(dti, dt):
    """
    dti - list of all the date times
    dt - single date time 
    """
    return min(dti, key=lambda x: abs(x - dt))

nearest(df.index, dt2)

solution inspired from here.
The key argument in the min function acts as a transformation on the initial iterable, which in this case is dti, before returning the min value of the transformed iterable.

One option is to reindex the dataframe with the full date range, then interpolate the values. Once you do that you can filter by any date inside the range.
import pandas as pd

# df from OP with added values
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["timestamp", "value"])
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-04"])
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)
df["value"] = [1, 2, 4]

out = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())).interpolate()

out = out.query("index == '2022-01-03'")

Or, if it's a large dataframe, instead of reindexing everything, you can isolate only the relevant section, considering the previous and next dates:
date_to_find = "2022-01-03"

if date_to_find in df.index:
    out = df.query(f"index == '{date_to_find}'")
else:
    prev_date = df.query(f"index < '{date_to_find}'").index.max()
    next_date = df.query(f"index > '{date_to_find}'").index.min()
    out = (
        df.reindex(pd.date_range(prev_date, next_date))
        .interpolate()
        .query(f"index == '{date_to_find}'")
    )

In both cases, out will be:
            value
2022-01-03    3.0


Thanks, how would I specify an actual datetime for index in "index = '2022-01-03'". I tried "index = {target_time}" which did not work

@Dave Try f"index == '{target_time}'" (with an f-string and wrapping the variable with '). Or just use something like out[out.index == target_time].

Example Code
we need example to answer your question.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt1 = pd.date_range("2008-01-01", periods=1000, freq="2d")
dt2 = pd.date_range("2008-01-01", periods=500, freq="7d")
np.random.seed(0)
val = np.random.randint(100, 900, len(dt1.union(dt2)))
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': val}, index=dt1.union(dt2))

df
            val
2008-01-01  784
2008-01-03  659
2008-01-05  729
... ...
2017-07-11  328
2017-07-18  156
2017-07-25  377
1357 rows × 1 columns

Code
when target = '2017-07-21' (not exist)
target = '2017-07-21'
prev_dt = df.index.to_series().lt(target).cumsum().idxmax()
next_dt = df.index.to_series().gt(target).idxmax()

out = df['val'].get(
    target,
    df['val'].reindex(
        [prev_dt, pd.to_datetime(target), next_dt]
    ).interpolate('time').get(target)
)

out
250.71428571428572


when target = '2017-07-18' (exist)
out
156


when target = '2017-07-21 12:00:00' (with time & not exist)
out
266.5

